# How do I add a space in front of my number if it is a single digit?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Working on a report that currently looks like this:

```
5 - Kirk Korver, UMKC
15 - Kendall Anthony, Richmond

Players With 30:
41 - Matt Staff, Texas State
```

I would like to make it look like the following:

```
  5 - Kirk Korver, UMKC
 15 - Kendall Anthony, Richmond

Players With 30:
41 - Matt Staff, Texas State
```

`*notice how the dashes are in line`

Is there a built in function in pl/sql that I can use?

Comment: You can usually do this in a language by left padding the result with a space and then using a RIGHT()-style function to pull off the two right characters from the resulting padded string. I don't know pl/sql or have a way to test to make sure anything I post is correct. Maybe someone else does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
LPAD(player_number, 2,' ')
```

Comment: What if player_number is a double digit?

Comment: @user1683987 LPAD(to_char(player_number), 2,' ')

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of it as "add a space in front of my number if it is a single digit."  Instead, you are printing a right-aligned space-padded two digit number.

You want to use the Oracle `TO_CHAR()` function like so.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( player_number, '99' ) AS formatted_player_number FROM....
```

Here's a [page that discusses number format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510).

Answer (score 0):

Can you do:

```
RIGHT('00' + cast([Id] AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS PaddedId
```

or

```
LPAD(Id, 2, '0')
```