# How can I tell Oracle that if the output is a single digit then put a space before it?

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a space in front of my number if it is a single digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631642/how-do-i-add-a-space-in-front-of-my-number-if-it-is-a-single-digit)

I have tried the following:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(to_char(myArray(i).myValue), '\d{1}', ' ' || to_char(myArrzy(i).myValue))
```

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lpad.php probably, though not sure about the types.

Comment: have you tried LPAD or RPAD?

Comment: Yes, I have tried LPAD, RPAD it's not doing anything. but remember I've got double digits as well, so I need some sort of a logic to only rpad it if it's a single digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lpad (to_char(myArray(i).myValue), 2, ' ')
```

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/rpad.html

Comment: It makes sense right? I dunno why it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: wierd, just replaced ' ' with an 'x' and it works...wonder why

Comment: maybe you are displaying in html - then you actually want &nbsp; ?

Comment: no, it's just sending an email or to a text editor. still can't figure it out! it is ignoring that space there. read somewhere that "Case, spaces and dashes are ignored during the comparisons in lpad" doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

how about just:

```sql
lpad(myArray(i).myValue,2)
```

The number will implicitly convert and ' ' is the default for `lpad`. [SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/5141)